# Instagram can't $_GET to token

Tags: php, html, api, token, instagram

The following url is an Instagram call with a token which is what I am trying to get to, a new token each time.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/785825990101768657/likes?access_token=1640112569.b7fd4cf.a915d0c8bada4609894807de1616df7b
```

note the periods in the token to make it work.

There are 2 auths available, an access code:

```
http://domain.co/instagram.php/?code=3dd01300d63f4685a7ee7b4359821119
```

Which fails

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/785825990101768657/likes?code=3dd01300d63f4685a7ee7b4359821119
```

error

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthParameterException","code":400,"error_message":"Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter."}}
```

and a token, which works

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/785825990101768657/likes?access_token=8515ebebfefa4f0f8b5412d2e834dfc2
```

But to get to it

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=333333333333333333&redirect_uri=http://domain.co/instagram.php/?&response_type=token
```

It returns the token with a # symbol rendering it useless.

```
http://favd.co/instagram.php/#access_token=1640112569.b7fd4cf.a915d0c8bada4609894807de1616df7b
```

I cannot $_GET to it.

How do I $_GET to the concatenated hash token/key on Instagram?

calling code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>


</head>

<body>

<div id="body">
<div id="mainContainer">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="text-align: center; background: none;">
                <div class="logo">
                        <h1 class="welcome">Welcome to</h1>
                </div>

                <div style="min-height: 100px">
                        <a href="favd.php">Facebook query object 'likes'!</a>
                        </br>
                        <!--
                        <a href="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=33333333333333333333333333&redirect_uri=http://domain.co/instagram.php/?&response_type=code">Instagram query object 'likes'!</a>  -->
                        <a href="https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=3333333333333333333333&redirect_uri=http://favd.co/instagram.php/?&response_type=token">Instagram query object 'likes'!</a>

<?php
$client_id = '11111111111111111111111';
$client_secret = '222222222222222222222';
$redirect_uri = 'http://favd.co/instagram.php/?';
$scope = 'basic+likes+comments+relationships';

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&scope=$scope&response_type=code";

if(!isset($_GET['code']))
{
        echo "</br>";
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Instagram query object \'hearts\'!</a>';
}
else
{
    $code = $_GET['code'];

$apiData = array(
  'client_id'       => $client_id,
  'client_secret'   => $client_secret,
  'grant_type'      => 'authorization_code',
  'redirect_uri'    => $redirect_uri,
  'code'            => $code
);

$apiHost = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiHost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($apiData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$jsonData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($jsonData);
$user = @json_decode($jsonData);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($user);
exit;
}
?>

                </div>
        </div>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like Instagram is foolishly insecure  ->  Note that we do not include an expiry time. Our access_tokens have no explicit expiry, though your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access  ->   http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/